# How to create route between 2 points using flutter_map package

Tags: flutter, mapbox, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I display a map using `flutter_map` package and `mapbox` but how can I make a routing between 2 points?

Like leaflet routing machine can we request a route using `mapbox`? If so how can I achieve that? I know I can draw a polyline but I don't know how to get the routing points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this question has been inactive for a while (but it might still help). I'd like to bring attention to http://project-osrm.org/. It's a free routing machine based on Open Street Maps.

I'm currently in the process of making a plugin for this (or a separate package with extra support for `flutter_map`), but I'm quite busy at the moment, so there's no ETA.

*See this comment on GitHub at https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map/issues/461#issuecomment-896993785*

Comment: We use self-hosted `https://hub.docker.com/r/giscience/openrouteservice` for generate route data (Polylines in GeoJSON format), and after this just draw it on the flutter map. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a open issue
(now closed due to stale issue without resolution) at https://github.com/johnpryan/flutter_map/issues/461. Please read